# Flutter Map , Emulator is not displaying current location, it is displaying GooglePlex location

Tags: android, flutter, dart, location

I am trying to display current location on my Google map. I have done everything, but it is not working. Its still showing google plex location Lat 37.42 , -112.08
I have tried running the apk on my physical device, I have added permissions. Also looked up some articles on the internet, I need some help.

Here is my codes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {

  String _locationMessage = "";

  void _getCurrentLocation() async {

    final position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);

    setState(() {
      _locationMessage = "${position.latitude}, ${position.longitude}";
    });

  }


  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text("Location Services")
            ),
            body: Align(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_locationMessage),
                    FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          _getCurrentLocation();
                        },
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Text("Find Location")
                    )
                  ]),
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set force Android Location Manager to true. Like this   **"position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low,
**forceAndroidLocationManager: true**);"**
then you will get the location on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me. Did you click on the set location button once you point somewhere in the map ?

[image]

Comment: Ohh okay, must I set my current location from  the map single point routes first before showing my location?

Comment: Thanks for your responds

Comment: I got this error while trying to build and test on a physical device. Note: C:\Users\Banky\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-6.1.12\android\src\mai
n\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\GeolocatorPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.